# ANGULAR - How to get specific element of object inside an array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have response api that i need specific element of object inside an array.

```
{
    "id": 61,
    "roleName": "ADMIN",
    "description": "ADMIN",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "permissionName": "addPermission",
            "description": "addPermission"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "permissionName": "updateTest",
            "description": "updateTest"
        }
    ]
 }
```

I expect the output is `"permissions": ["addPermission","updateTest"]` in Angular typescript

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Probably some attempts you did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be just so many ways to do this, one of them could be using [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let data = {
            "id": 61,
            "roleName": "ADMIN",
            "description": "ADMIN",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": 23,
                    "permissionName": "addPermission",
                    "description": "addPermission"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "permissionName": "updateTest",
                    "description": "updateTest"
                }
            ]
}

let desiredData = {permissions: data.permissions.map(p => p.permissionName)}

console.log(desiredData)
```